# Paging library cachedIn() function doesn't work when using function

Tags: android, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

I am a little bit confused. I am trying to implement pagination 3 library. When I working on it I figured something out. If I use pagedItems() method to collect flow cachedIn() is not working. The function sends new request again after device rotated. However, if I use pagedItems value everything is perfectly fine.

The question is I've noticed that when I try to collect flows from these methods after device rotated pagedItems() function's hashcode is changing but pagedItems value's is not. What's the diffrence between them why one of them's hashcode is changing but other's not?

**ViewModel**

```
// Working perfectly fine
val pagedItems = useCase.invoke(PAGE_SIZE).cachedIn(viewModelScope)

// Working without caching feature
fun pagedItems(): Flow<PagingData<Result>> {
    return useCase.invoke(PAGE_SIZE).cachedIn(viewModelScope) 
}
```

**Fragment**

```
viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            // It's working fine
            launch {
                viewModel.pagedItems.collect { pagedData ->
                    pagingAdapter.submitData(pagedData)
                }
            }
            // It sends request again
            launch {
                viewModel.pagedItems().collect { pagedData ->
                    pagingAdapter.submitData(pagedData)
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

`fun pagedItems()` will return different instance of flow for every single call. That's why we need to use `val` keyword. It will solve the problem.

```
// Working perfectly fine
val pagedItems = useCase.invoke(PAGE_SIZE).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your `useCase`, you are creating an instance of `Pager`. In the val case, you do that only once and it's stored in your `ViewModel` which survives configuration changes. In the function case, you create new instance of `Pager` every time you call the function, which is every time your Fragment is recreated.